# How to get "appendChild" created divs to use styles that already exist

Tags: javascript, css, styles, appendchild

Im creating some divs and assigning some CSS styles with the div class attribute.  The CSS styles are already defined in my css stylesheet and already have properties for borders and color defined.  The issue is when
I create new divs with the pre-defined classes the styling is not displayed.

```js
this.round = 0;


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "guess-cell");
  document.getElementsByClassName("row")[this.round + 2].appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
.guess-cell {
  padding-top: 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: var(--main-color-light);
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The styles apply when I test it: https://i.imgur.com/NokDtcu.png

Comment: @Quentin i dont know if it matters but im doing it in vue, i coud give the hole file for you to replicate but stackoverflow wont allow it

Comment: It probably matters a *lot*. I've never used Vue, but I assume that it works like React and has a behind-the-scenes DOM which it then overlays on the actual DOM, and you should use Vue methods to update the DOM and not directly manipulate things using the DOM API. Don't show me the "whole file", edit the question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Try this one [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wjrp4f7d/1/) i have used getElementById

Answer (score 0):

@ruben-tapadas you are trying to use custom properties in CSS but you haven't defined the custom properties in your snippet.  You need to add in the custom properties.

For example:

```
:root {
   --main-color-light: coral;
   --main-color: blue;
}
```

So your overall code snippet would now look like

```js
this.round = 0;


for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "guess-cell");
  document.getElementsByClassName("row")[this.round + 2].appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color-light: coral;
  --main-color: blue;
}

.guess-cell {
  padding-top: 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: var(--main-color-light);
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Try it out now and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
div.classList.add("guess-cell");
```

Instead of setAttribute.